# Accessing help files across domains using relative path

Tags: html, dom

I have two separate applications deployed on two separate app servers. However, help files for both apps reside in a single app. When I click within app1 > help, it should access HTML help pages that are inside app2.

App1: `http://<APP SERVER 1>/app1`
App2: `http://<APP SERVER 2>/app2`

Help files: `http://<APP SERVER 2>/app2/help/index.html`

Problem:
Within app1, I have hard-coded the URL of help files alongwith the server URL.

`<a href="http://<APP SERVER 2>/app2/help/createProd.html">Create Product</a>`

When there is change in server IP, I need to change the IP again in href.

What is a way to put relative path to non-local resources?

Thanks in advance.